# error using CArray

Tags: c++, mfc

So, I am trying to use `CArray` like this :

```
 CArray<CPerson,CPerson&> allPersons;
   int i=0;
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
      allPersons.SetAtGrow(i,CPerson(i));
      i++;
   }
```

But when compiling my program, I get this error :

> "error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' :
>   cannot access private member declared
>   in class 'CObject'    c:\program
>   files\microsoft visual studio
>   9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtempl.h"

I don't even understand where this is coming from.

HELP!

Comment: It seems the problem is related to the fact that CObject has a private constructor. 
what step should I take to solve the problem ? waiting to hear from you,
Thanks.

Comment: There are two i++ statements in this loop, though that's probably not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the error listed comes from the code you have shown?

Comment: crashmstr, yes , the error comes from the code i've shown.

Comment: See my update below. The code compiles. It is very wrong in some senses, but it compiles (and it was taken from your snippet from a comment)

Comment: crashmstr,

i'm aware the code is wrong in soe sens, i'm just learning about CArray, it's for educational purposes.

Thanks for your efforts in helping me.

Comment: The wrong was more about sprintf to an unallocated char * and possibly having two increments in a for loop by mistake. Look at my answer bellow. It compiles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to use a `CArray` as a return value from what I can gather. If you change it from returning a `CArray` to taking a reference parameter instead, that will compile.

Try this:

```
class CPerson
{
public:
    CPerson();
    CPerson(int i);
    void operator=(const CPerson& p) {}
private:
    char* m_strName;
};

CPerson::CPerson()
{}

CPerson::CPerson(int i)
{
    sprintf(m_strName,"%d",i);
}

void aFunction(CArray<CPerson,CPerson&> &allPersons)
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        allPersons.SetAtGrow(i,CPerson(i));
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: CArray was templated but it was not properly visible. Pls see the edited version.

Comment: this is my aFunction : can the problem be related to it ?

CFeed<CFeed,CFeed&> aFunction()
{
  CArray<CPerson,CPerson&> allPersons;

  int i=0;
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
      allPersons.SetAtGrow(i,CPerson(i)); i++;
  }

return allPerson;
}

Comment: yep. That is the problem. The CArray cannot be returned like that it seems.

Comment: That is the problem. Your function aFunction() tries to call copy constructor of CArray and it is defined private in CObject. Please refer to my answer

Comment: You can also change the signature of the function to take CArray& as input param and modify the same in loop.

Comment: I don't think Attilah wants a copy per se, but an initialized array.

Comment: crashmstr,

thanks.
man, C++/MFC can really make me look older in less than a month.
i'm used to C#/.NET. this seems so difficult sometimes.

Comment: I started more or less with C++ & MFC, but C# and .Net can make some things a lot easier.

Comment: If possible use std::vector instead of CArray, and then you can get the array as the return value.

Comment: @sergiol yes, using standard C++ containers is much nicer than the MFC container classes, but if there is a lot of existing code it might not be straightforward to change.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using any of the Copy constructor or assignment operator of CObject ? ( CArray is derived from CObject)

For instance:

```
 CArray<CPerson,CPerson&> allPersons;  

//do something

// This gives the error C2248, cannot access Copy constructor of CObject.
CArray<CPerson,CPerson&> aTemp = allPersons;
```

OR

Are you doing this?

```
CArray<CPerson,CPerson&> allPersons; 
...
CArray<CPerson,CPerson&> aTemp;

//Error, as Assignment operator is private
aTemp = allPersons;
```

**EDIT**:
If you want to copy the elements in CArray, write a helper method CopyArray() and copy the elements manually.

```
CopyArray(sourceArray, DestArray&)
{
 for each element in SourceArray
 add the element to DestArray.
}
```

Comment: no, i didn't do any of the things you cited. i just did this :

CArray<CPerson,CPerson&> allPersons;
   int i=0;
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
      allPersons.SetAtGrow(i,CPerson(i));
      i++;
   }

Comment: This code looks correct. Can you post CPerson definition. By any chance CPerson derived from CObject?

Comment: //person.h
class CPerson
{
  public:
     CPerson();
     CPerson(int i);
  private:
     char* m_strName;
}

//person.cpp
CPerson::CPerson()
{
}
CPerson::CPerson(int i)
{
  sprintf(m_strName,"%d",i);
}

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that CArray tries to call the constructor of CObject but that constructor is private.

How to circumvent this ?

Comment: I just compiled what you had, and it works (with syntax fixes)

Comment: CObject constructor is protected and protected constructors are allowed for base classes. CArray is derived from CObject.

Comment: Or you could call void CArray::Copy(const CArray& src), no helper method needed unless you are working with different templates of CArray

Comment: Yeah, copy can be used. Or pass the Array as input param by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to say `CArray<CPerson> allPersons;` ? I don't know how leaving out the contained type would lead to the reported error, but...

Comment: Mark, I think you're mistaken(maybe), but i think it should be CArray(CPerson,CPerson&> allPersons. it takes 2 parameters.

Comment: The second parameter is optional, if omitted, it will be the same as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Is `CPerson` derived from `CObject`?  Does it have a `private` constructor?  Your use of `SetAtGrow()` seems correct to me otherwise.

If that doesn't work, you might try falling back to using the `Add()` function, as your loop doesn't seem to require `SetAtGrow()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure of what your problem was, but take also a look at this: [Microsoft CObject derived class specifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccb3dh5c.aspx).

You might want to add this code:

```
class Person
{
    // ...
    Person( const Person& src );
}

Person::Person( const Person& src ){ Person();*this = src; }
```

Hope it helps for the future.

Answer (score 0):

If `CPerson` is a complex object, maybe you should consider using [pointers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers.htm)

```
   CArray<CPerson*,CPerson*> allPersons;
   int i=0;
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      allPersons.SetAtGrow(i,new CPerson(i));
```

Don't forget to delete your array's content once it's not needed anymore

```
   for(int i=0;i<allPersons.GetSize();i++)
      delete allPersons.GetAt(i);
```