# "error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'

Tags: c++, mfc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error using CArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864864/error-using-carray)

Duplicate : [error using CArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864864/error-using-carray)

---

so, i am trying to use CArray like this :

```
   CArray<CPerson,CPerson&> allPersons;
   int i=0;
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
      allPersons.SetAtGrow(i,CPerson(i));
      i++;
   }
```

but when compiling my program, i get this error :

```
"error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtempl.h"
```

I don't even understand where this is coming from.

HELP !

Comment: Duplicate from same author: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864864/error-using-carray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a constructor for your class (CPerson) and make it public. it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 24):

The problem is that you're constructing a CObject on the stack.  Somewhere in your program you're attempting to pass a reference to a CArray object but you accidentally left out the "&" in the function prototype.  For example:

```
void DoFoo(CArray cArr)
{
    // Do something to cArr...
}
```

^^^ The code above will cause the error you're having.

```
void DoFoo(CArray & cArr)
{
    // Do something to cArr...
}
```

^^^ The code above will not cause the problem.

Comment: This was exactly what I had done and chased the problem around until I searched here.  Good call.

Comment: It doesn't even need to be a missing & in the function prototype.  The problem in my code was missing & in variable declaration.

Comment: It worked for me.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It means that your program is trying to construct an instance of `CObject`, which appears to be banned because `CObject` has a private constructor.

Maybe the `CArray` is trying to construct those instances? What does the rest of the program look like?

Comment: yes, i think it has to do with the fact that CArray is trying to construct an instance of CObject.
but how do I circumvent the problem ?

Comment: Like I asked, what does the rest of the program look like? Post the shortest complete program that will demonstrate the problem, omitting the stuff generated by any wizards, etc.