# Return a CStringArray gives errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

Im trying to return a CStringArray:
In my ".h" I defined:

```
    Private:
    CStringArray array;

    public:
    CStringArray& GetArray();
```

In . cpp I have:

```
    CQueue::CQueue()
    {
    m_hApp = 0;
    m_default = NULL;
    }


    CQueue::~CQueue()
    {

     DeleteQueue();
    }

    CStringArray& CQueue::GetArray()
    {

     return array;   
    }
```

From another file I'm trying to call it by:

```
    CStringArray LastUsedDes = cqueue.GetArray();
```

I guess it is because of the above line that I get the error:

```
   error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864864/error-using-carray

Comment: Are you sure that's the piece of code that's generating the error? Returning a reference to the `CStringArray` should work, that error usually shows up when you try to return by value.

Comment: I had returned it using a vector. It works fine. It is here that the problem is

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865035/error-c2248-cobjectcobject-cannot-access-private-member-declared-in-clas - another that might point you in the right direction

Comment: @user1563551 Then please post a complete, compilable example that reproduces the error.

Comment: I really dont know where else to look into. HELP..Is there anything that needs to be changed in the constructor?

Comment: @user1563551 How can anyone tell you if anything needs to be changed in the constructor when you haven't posted the code? It is not possible to help you unless you post some code we can try compiling ourselves to figure out what is going on. Start taking stuff out of your class until it is as small as possible and still produces the same error message. Then post the class definition here along with some code showing how you're using it.

Comment: out of curiosity, if you have your array set to public anyway, why don't you just access the data with the dot operator. Most people will frown upon that, but hey, if you're in a hurry.

Comment: @user1563551 When replying to someone you need to not make typos while typing their usernames, or the person does not get notified. On all browsers I've used (except for mobile browsers) if you type `@` and then the first couple of characters of their username a popup appears and you can just hit the tab key to auto-complete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is on this line

```
CStringArray LastUsedDes = cqueue.GetArray();
```

Even though you're returning a reference to the `CStringArray` in the `GetArray()` function a copy of the array is being made in the line above. `CStringArray` itself doesn't define a copy constructor and it derives from `CObject`, which has a private copy constructor.

Change the line to

```
CStringArray& LastUsedDes = cqueue.GetArray();
```

But be aware that `LastUsedDes` now refers to the same `CStringArray` contained in your class instance, and any changes made to one will be visible in the other.

If you need a local copy of the returned array you can use the `Append` member function to copy the contents.

```
CStringArray LastUsedDes;                // default construct the array
LastUsedDes.Append( cqueue.GetArray() ); // this will copy the contents of the
                                         // returned array to the local array
```

Comment: these Microsoft guys could have made the people's life simpler by just implementing something like `public: CStringArray(const CStringArray& src) {Append(src);}`