# CObject, CStringArray and error C2248

Tags: arrays, mfc

```
class MyClass : public CObject
{
public:
   MyClass();

private:
   CStringArray m_myArray;
};
```

causes error c2248

What's wrong with this ?
I think it's related to the fact that CStringArray and MyClass both derive from CObject.

Legacy class derived from CObject currently uses CustomArray it just seems wrong to me so I would like to replace it by CStringArray.

Comment: Did you try clicking on the error to take you to the location of the problem?

Comment: As an aside comment, I would use std::vector<CString> rather than CStringArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft compiler error [C2248](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsbce2bh.aspx) means "Members of a derived class cannot access private members of a base class."

I can only assume you're trying to directly reference `MyClass::m_myArray` from somewhere in your code, without using a public accessor function.

**Update**
The real answer is that the problem is caused by the copy-constructor for MyClass, attempting to copy m_myArray, but it can't, because CObject derived classes aren't copyable by default. The solution would be to write a copy constructor yourself, and rather than attempt to copy the array, copy the contents one at a time, from the source array to the destination array. Either that or use `std::vector` (which you should be doing anyway, as MFC containers are horrible).

Comment: error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : impossible d'accéder à private membre déclaré(e) dans la classe 'CObject' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxcoll.h 590

Stops at that typedef LPCTSTR BASE_ARG_TYPE; of class CStringArray

Comment: When I try it in Visual Studio 2010, it works absolutely fine for me. Try using std::vector<CString> instead of CStringArray.

Comment: I'd rather use CStringArray for the moment and stick to the MFC than mixing frameworks with std::vector<CString>. Following what you say std::vector<std::string> would be better, but that's another question.

Comment: Ok, seems that using std::vector is the easiest solution. My problem was similar to this one : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/20fb3603-8461-46f3-8c4f-bab5254a9669

Comment: What's more I realized that's what the CustomArray class in my legacy code was for, to solve that problem.

Comment: Ah OK, then the real answer is that the problem is caused by the copy-constructor for MyClass, attempting to copy m_myArray, but it can't, because CObject derived classes aren't copyable by default.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access some private member of `CObject`. Since both your `MyClass` and `CStringArray` derive from `CObject`, without more context it is impossible to know the exact problem.

The only idea that comes to mind, basically because I've fallen in the trap many times, is that `CObject`'s copy constructor is private, so if you are trying to copy either the `CStringArray` or your own class, explicit or implicitly, you'll get the error.

**UPDATE:**
I've just taken a look at `CObject`'s declaration and the assignment operator, too, is private. Everything else is either public or protected.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833496/return-a-cstringarray-gives-errors

Answer (score 0):

Error `C2248` says "Members of a derived class cannot access private members of a base class."

CStringArray class dosn't expose Copy constructor and assignment operator, look in code for such places and replace the code with elemenet by elemnet copy.