# How to use CArray inside CArray in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to use custom array in new array like these.

```
typedef CArray<CPoint,CPoint&> arr1;
typedef CArray<arr1,arr1&> arr2;

arr1 a;
arr2 b;

b.Add(a);
```

I get this error :

> error C2248: 'CObject::operator =' : cannot access private member
>   declared in class 'CObject'

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865035/error-c2248-cobjectcobject-cannot-access-private-member-declared-in-clas)

Comment: What's wrong with `std::vector` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error using CArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864864/error-using-carray)

Comment: Should I create a new class for arr1 which it must inherit from array of Cpoint?

Comment: Yes. @Andrew below shows you how. CObject has private copy constructor and assignment operator. If I were you, I'd probably just use the STL vector class instead of adding more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `CArray` does not have copy constructor and `operator=()`. But you can easily extend this class and implement the required functionality:

```
template <class TYPE, class ARG_TYPE>
class CArrayEx : public CArray<TYPE, ARG_TYPE>
{
// Construction
public:
    CArrayEx ()
    {
    };
    CArrayEx (const CArrayEx &x)
    {
        *this = x;
    };

// Assigment
public:
    CArrayEx &operator = (const CArrayEx &x)
    {
        if(this != &x)
        {
            Copy(x);
        }

        return *this;
    };
};
```

After that you can define your own types like this:

```
typedef CArrayEx<CPoint, CPoint&> CPointArray;
typedef CArray<CPointArray, CPointArray&> CDoublePointArray;
```

And here is the pretty simple example on how to use it:

```
    CDoublePointArray doubleArray;

    CPointArray singleArray;
    singleArray.Add(CPoint(10,10));

    doubleArray.Add(singleArray);
```

As an alternative solution to `CArray` I would suggest using `std::vector`. You can use it out-of-the-box as it comes with copy constructor.