# VS2013 compiler: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'

Tags: c++, c++11, mfc

I'm trying to migrate a project from to c++11 in Visual Studio. I fixed a number of issues, but there's one remaining which I can't seem to crack with MFC:

```
error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject' (file.cpp)
: see declaration of 'CObject::CObject'
: see declaration of 'CObject'
This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'CList<ParameterValue,ParameterValue &>::CList(const CList<ParameterValue,ParameterValue &> &)'
```

This is code that hasn't changed on our end and has been compiling fine when targeting the Visual Studio 2010 toolset. From what I could gather it doesn't seem like the definition of CObject has changed either which makes it all the stranger.

There's other similar questions reported here, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem there. In most other cases it would appear the issue comes from a lack of public default constructors, Copy constructors, or assignment operators.

Our class that extends CList however provides public versions of all these, and ParameterValue does not inherit from CObject.

```
class __declspec(dllexport) GParameterValueList : public CList<ParameterValue, ParameterValue&>
{
// ParameterValue is a struct that DOES NOT inherit from CObject (or anything)
public:
    GParameterValueList();
    GParameterValueList(const GParameterValueList& SrcList);
    GParameterValueList& operator=(const GParameterValueList& SrcList);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.Our implementation is exported into a DLL, I'm wondering if that might be causing some conflicts?

Edit: Not a duplicate of [error using CArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864864/error-using-carray) or [error using CArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864864/error-using-carray) -> in these the CObject derived classes were missing public default and copy constructors. As described above, this is not the case with our code.

Comment: What does `GParameterValueList` copy constructor look like? Does it attempt to delegate to the copy constructor of its base class, by any chance? `CList` doesn't have one to delegate to.

Comment: No, the copy constructor goes through the other list, copies each ParameterValue and then pushes it to the back of the current list. The normal constructor does nothing and the operator= does pretty much the same as the copy constructor.

Comment: One way or the other, somewhere in the code you haven't shown, `CList`'s copy constructor is being invoked. Figure out where and how.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your ParameterValue class. Try to declare **public** constructors in there, including the default constructor. 
It seems to me that the CList tries to call the ParameterValue constructor somewhere, but the former can't because the latter is private.

Alternatively, try to use a List of Pointers, like `CList<ParameterValue*, ParameterValue*&>`.

Another alternative is to use a std container instead of CList.